# Get XML node id by text attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file, a section of it shown here below.

```
 <node id="413" text="plant1">
   <node id="419" text="Detail Reports">
     <node id="424" text="Bulk Lactol" reportid="14" nodetype="1"/>
     <node id="427" text="Effluent" reportid="17" nodetype="1"/>
     <node id="425" text="Pasteurisers" reportid="15" nodetype="1"/>
     <node id="421" text="Tank 8" reportid="12" nodetype="1"/>
     <node id="420" text="Tank 9" reportid="11" nodetype="1"/>
   </node>
   <node id="422" text="Summary Reports">
     <node id="423" text="plant1 Summary" reportid="13" nodetype="1"/>
     <node id="426" text="Effluent Summary" reportid="16" nodetype="1"/>
   </node>
 </node>
```

I am trying to get the 'node id' by the 'text' value.
I tried the following.

```
string y = "Bulk Lactol"
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\Users\\Joe\\Desktop\\wt.xml");
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(y);
string x = Convert.ToString(node);
```

But I am getting an exception:

> 'Bulk Lactol' has an invalid token.

I found some similar questions but I am not very familiar with XML so I was having trouble adapting them to my problem, Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectSingleNode` and `SelectNodes` accept [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) string as an argument.

You can use the following XPath to find this item:

```
string y = "Bulk Lactol";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\Users\\Joe\\Desktop\\wt.xml");

XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//node[@text='Bulk Lactol']");
string x = node.InnerText;
```

`//node[@text='Bulk Lactol']` XPath means

> any element in the hierarchy which has an attribute "text" with value "Bulk Lactol"

Comment: Don't forget to select the @id